# Remote selenium grid can't receive string from scanner, but local does

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenide

```
 private File f = new File("src/test/resources/text.txt");
 final String projectUrl = "http://someurl.com"


 @BeforeTest
 public void setUp() {
 Configuration.remote = "http://some.ip.address.129:4444/hub"
 }

 @Test
 public void smallOrderTest() throws FileNotFoundException {
   try {
       s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f.getAbsolutePath())));
       while (s.hasNext()) {
         open(projectUrl+s.next())
         }
       } finally {
           if (s != null) {
               s.close();
           }
         }
 }
```

What's my question. 
When I remove configuration string, I receive nice test on my local environment. 
But whet that string is here, test doesn't runs ever, and prints this:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Need full stack trace?

Question is - what I'm doing wrong? How to solve this? I need to run remote tests, check links string by string from the file, and not on my local environment.

Local OS Linux Mint 17, Selenide 3.4, Selenium 2.53.0, run from Idea,
Remote VM Win7, with Selenium standalone server hub and one node.
Driver standard Firefox.

Fails at "open" command, if I set remote server in Configuration.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.util.Map
>
> at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:251)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:158)
>     at
>   com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createRemoteDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:36)
>     at
>   com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.createDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:213)
>     at
>   com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:113)
>     at
>   com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverRunner.java:118)
>     at
>   com.codeborne.selenide.impl.Navigator.navigateToAbsoluteUrl(Navigator.java:44)
>     at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.Navigator.open(Navigator.java:23)    at
>   com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:51)    at
>   SmallOrder.smallOrderTest(SmallOrder.java:44)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)   at
>   org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:74)     at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:121)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Comment: Full stack always helps.
Add more details about grid configuration, which driver, which OS, in which line ex. occured.

Comment: @SkorpEN  Added stacktrace, configurationm and driver-os with line

Comment: What is in line 144 in AppMain ???

Comment: @SkorpEN I think it's something from IntelliJ Idea, which IDE I use.
http://joxi.ru/EA4zKBQSDl0d4m there is no link, to look what's there.

Comment: in your class AppMain what is in line 144

Comment: @SkorpEN I haven't that class. Only one, named SmallOrder.java

Comment: Ok. what happend in SmallOrder.java in line 44 ???

Comment: @SkorpEN that command opens url projectUrl+s.next() where s.next is string from text file extracted via scanner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112379/discussion-between-boris-and-skorpen).

Answer (score 0):

Initializing RemoteWebDriver requires setting DesiredCapabilities (as can be seen in [WebDriver's source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-2.53.0/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java)).

I am not a Selenide user, but it seems with version 3.4 this is a bit painful, so you can try upgrading to the latest version and use [Configuration.browserCapabilities](http://selenide.org/javadoc/current/com/codeborne/selenide/Configuration.html#browserCapabilities)

Or, if you have no such option, see an example here: https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/issues/444